# Makefile evaluating target name to empty string

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to make a makefile without having to manually type out all my targets.

I have a file for just about every function with the same name as the function, and then another file with the same name followed by '_test' which contains a main method trying to use the function (not super rigorous but I don't need full unit tests).

my Makefile looks like this:

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
TARGETS = add_tag tag_known

$(TARGETS) : $(addsuffix _test.o, $@) $@.o
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(addsuffix _test, $@) $(addsuffix _test.o, $@) $@.o

%.o : %.c 
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean :
   rn -f *.o $(TARGETS) $(addsuffix _test, $(TARGETS))
```

Everything is working except for the first target. The requirements, $(addsuffix _test.o, $@) etc, it appears that they're just evaluating to empty strings, which causes the C compiler to throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gotchya here is that automatic variables (`$@` in this case) can't be used in the prerequisite list of the rule https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html

> Also, they cannot be accessed directly within the prerequisite list of a rule. A common mistake is attempting to use $@ within the prerequisites list; this will not work.

But on the plus side, you can fix this multiple ways! One way is with "secondary expansion". The docs that I linked go through that in some depth if you're interested. I personally have a hard time understanding makefiles that use secondary expansion heavily, so I'd steer you towards the other fix I can think of which is to define the prerequesites of the first target in terms of the `TARGETS` variable like this which should just work:

```
$(TARGETS) : $(addsuffix _test.o, $(TARGETS)) $(addsuffix .o, $(TARGETS))
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(addsuffix _test, $@) $(addsuffix _test.o, $@) $@.o
```

Comment: This is not right: it won't do what you want, if the `TARGETS` variable has more than one value.  Basically it will make every individual `TARGETS` value depend on _all_ the object files not just the object files for that target.

Comment: Thanks! Great response, now I can get back to segfaulting 

Comment: @MadScientist is right here -- the dependencies are going to be a bit messed up (can test by running `touch tag_known_test.c` then `make` and everything will recompile), so you're probably better up using the "pattern rule" solution they posted if your project gets too big to compile

Comment: On the other hand, due to the `-o $(addsuffix _test,$@)` issue I mentioned in my answer, every binary will always be rebuilt every time you run make anyway, _even if_ you don't change any source files.  So the issue I pointed to above won't even come into play (at least not until you fix that) :).

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work:

```
$(TARGETS) : $(addsuffix _test.o, $@) $@.o
```

If you examine the documentation for automatic variables like `$@` etc. you'll see they're only set in the context of the rule recipe.  They have no value outside the recipe (in this case, in the prerequisite list).

You can use a pattern rule for this:

```
% : %.o %_test.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

or, probably better, use a static pattern rule:

```
$(TARGETS) : % : %.o %_test.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Note that this:

```
-o $(addsuffix _test, $@)
```

is always(*) wrong.  Every recipe should create the exact name of the target (that is, `$@`) not some other file.  If your rule lies to make about what it does, then make will get very confused.

(*) Just like anything, there can be rare situations where this is useful.